# Powershell: add users to the ADDS with a csv file

Tags: powershell

It's been some time that I try to add several users in the adds with a CSV file, but I'm lost. I do not understand much, it's the first time I do PowerShell.

CSV File:

```
"firstname","lastname","username","departement","changePWlogon","OU",,
James,Gun,Gunny,auto,true,"OU=prod,DC=test,DC=local"
Luc,Skywalker,Walker,science,false,"OU=admin,DC=test,DC=local"
Harry,Potter,Hpot,auto,true,"OU=prod,DC=test,DC=local"
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: i presume that `adds` is windows active directory. [*grin*] what have you tried? what have you searched for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new-aduser and import-csv not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761907/new-aduser-and-import-csv-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you cannot add users to the CSV file? Consider this function

```
function writeToFile($fileName, $content){
    $content = $content -join "`r`n"
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter ($fileName) $true
    $stream.NewLine = "`r`n"
    $stream.WriteLine($content)
    $stream.close()
}
```

The `$true` boolean when calling the constructor of [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) means that content is *appended* (added) to your file. `$fileName` expects the full path to your .csv file. 
`$content` is an array of data to be added to your .csv. In your example:

```
$content = "Harry","Potter","hpot","auto,"true","OU=prod,DC=test,DC=local"
```